# How to get visible SPField's for a specific list view

Tags: list, query

I am trying to enumerate a list based on a selected view - basically, programmatically doing what is visually shown when viewing a list.

I will be using this to output a file, so I am first getting all the fields and then each item setup as a table, eg:

```
Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4
Item1Field1, Item1Field2, Item1Field3, Item1Field4
Item2Field1, Item2Field2, Item2Field3, Item2Field4
```

My problem is, I only want the fields that are visible when you view it on the page. I build the query using this:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery(list.Views['Viewname']);
query.RowLimit = uint.MaxValue;
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
```

I can then get the fields that are given in the views using `items.QueryFieldNames` (or alternatively `list.Views['Viewname'].ViewFields`, but they are identical). However, these fields use the internal names and for obvious reasons I want to display the DisplayName for each field. I tried using `list.Fields[viewfield]`, but it only takes a GUID, an index or the DisplayName, neither of which I have.

Is there any smart way to get a list of `SPField`s for a specific view / query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you're looking for the [SPList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.getfieldbyinternalname.aspx) method. This will allow you to get the field by it's internal name, like this:

```
foreach (string fieldName in list.Views['Viewname'].ViewFields)
{
    var field = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(fieldName)
    // do whatever you need with SPField object
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SPFields are defined at the list level, not to an individual view or query.  Instead of `list.Fields[viewfield]`, try this : `list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(viewfield)`

more info : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.getfieldbyinternalname.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have the internal name so you can get the display name as shown below:

```
list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(internalName).Title
```